# What is the best Lightweight/high performance embedded web-server for implementing REstful API

Tags: java, performance, web-services, rest, webserver

What is the best Lightweight/high performance embedded web-server for implementing REstful API. I need to interface it with java code.
can anyone suggest me the best solution for it? as I am newbie in this field

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think finding "the best" cotnainer in terms of performance is very hard task and it is based on your particular use case, meaning - how will you use it? Since it's RESTful API, I guess you will be interested in serving large number of clients with some simple services. So if I were you, I would look for server which is stable for huge amount of requests.

Please check out [this](http://www.webperformance.com/library/reports/ServletReport/) interesting article to give you more insights on the performance topic.

Personally, I would go with [embedded tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html) or [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) is what you're looking for, although it would be a good idea to also check others (like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), for instance) to see which one's the most suitable for your needs.